# How to interpret Jump far FF assembly instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have 3 classes:

```
class Base { virtual foo() {...} }
class A : Base { virtual foo() override {...} }
class B : A { virtual bar() {...} /* introduce bar, but no foo override */ }
```

and I want to understand how this virtual function calls works under the hood.

If I call `A a; a.foo()` - the compiler generates `Call` instruction `FF 10` which leads to near-jump instruction `E9 01 02 03 04`. The last 4 bytes - relative offset from vtable-record to real function. It is pretty obvious and clear. But if I call `B b; b.foo()` - the `Call` instruction leads to another kind of Jump `FF 25`. Visual Studio disassemblers displays it like this:

```
00007FFA2CAB1C85 FF 25 AD 76 21 01    jmp         qword ptr [A::foo (07FFA2DCC9338h)]
```

I expected to get jump to `07FFA2DCC9338h` address, but instead, it jumps to `07FFA4AD05885h`(I suppose VS is lying with predicted address):

```
00007FFA4AD05885 E9 96 5D 01 00       jmp         A::foo (07FFA4AD1B620h)
```

And this jump instuction (`E9`) forwards me to the real function.

But I do not understand how `FF 25` works. Unfortunately, my assembly knowledge is very poor, I read [some documentation](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html), it says about some "gates", and I do not understand it.

**Is it possible to predict the jump location for far-jump(`FF`) by having current instruction address(`RIP`) and jump-arguments?**

Comment: That is not a far jump. That is a near indirect jump. The `07FFA2DCC9338h` is the address of a pointer in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Jester, seems you are right.

`E9` - jumps to specific relative code instruction.
`FF 25` - calculates some specific relative location, read the memory from there, and use this memory as a pointer to next code instruction.

I just detected that

```
E9 ...      jmp     A::foo (07FFA4AD1B620h)
FF 25 ...   jmp     qword ptr [A::foo (07FFA2DCC9338h)]
```

**qword ptr[...]** says that I should derefer the value!